# Simple layout inflating - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-arrayadapter

I have custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class PostPreviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostPreviewItem> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<PostPreviewItem> mPostPreviewItems;
int resource;
public PostPreviewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PostPreviewItem> itemArrayList) {
    super(context, resource, itemArrayList);
    mContext = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    mPostPreviewItems = itemArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview_post_title);
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview_post_description);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview_post_image);
        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    PostPreviewItem postPreviewItem = getItem(position);

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(postPreviewItem != null) {
        // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(postPreviewItem.getTitle());
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(postPreviewItem.getDescription());
        if (postPreviewItem.getImageUrl()!=null & !postPreviewItem.getImageUrl().isEmpty())
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(postPreviewItem.getImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
    }

    return convertView;

}
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView titleTextView;
    TextView descriptionTextView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

}

And receive `OutOfMemoryError` inflating the layout:

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
```

I initialise it in following way:

```
 PostPreviewAdapter adapter = new PostPreviewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.post_preview_item,arrayList);
```

My item is:

```
public class PostPreviewItem  {
    String imageUrl;
    String title;
    String description;

    }
```

I do not include the image at all in the ArrayList of the Adapter for the test. 
What can be the reason of it? 
Thanks

Here is my xml:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview_post_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/regular_corner_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/regular_top"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/preview_post_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/preview_post_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/regular_top"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/preview_post_description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/preview_post_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/preview_post_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>
```

Comment: I guess your layout is not optimized. post your xml please

Comment: How many elements are stored in `ArrayList<PostPreviewItem> mPostPreviewItems` ?

Comment: @Rikki please post the whole stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace of an out of memory error doesn't necessarily point to the cause of the memory problem. Once your memory is tight, any action allocating memory can trigger the exception. And since inflating a layout allocates a reasonable amount of memory, it's a more likely candidate to trigger it. So you need to do a more fundamental analysis of the problem. But my experience is, out of memory is most often due to a too large number of too big images in memory.

Comment: Your images might be very big in size try adding 'android:largeHeap=true' in manifest, that might solve your issue but the better approach is to optimise image size

Comment: Please post the complete xml `R.layout.post_preview_item`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to incorrect processing of picture
and advise you to use a [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or same library